list of non-impimented functions? (GCC)
I'm looking at a LARGE code base 800 C  files, 700 or so H files
There are a number of cases where:
(A) a prototype exists in a header
But
(B) there is no actual implementation of the function.
I can solve (B) - but no (A).
To Solve (B) - I can compile everything and get symbol tables out of the object files  that tells me what exists and is implemented.
To solve (A) - I have no means to extract DECLARED lists in header files etc in the form of a list.
NOTE: This is not a problem that:  -Wimplicit-function-declaration will solve. The functions are implemented across the 800 or so C files (and some a few ASM files, these are covered because I will just run "nm" on all object files).
In some/many cases the developers wrote a list of "gee we should have these" functions, but never actually implemented the functions. Grr...
Is there a way to get this list of prototypes and globals vars out of GCC?
VISUAL studio does this - it puts squiggly green lines under the function name
but - I'm not using Visual Studio

It isn't quite clear what the actual problem is. Are you trying to extract a list of declared but unimplemented functions?

yes exactly. put another way if i can get a list of all declared functions and variables in each of my 800 translation units, then i can later post process the 800 lists and come up with a list of missing implementations

When you compile and link, you'll get "undefined function" errors for all the unimplemented functions.

Not the case - that only occurs if they are used in the application. If the function is not used, there is no error and no warning.

ctags is your friend.
 ctags --kinds-c=f -ofunctions.lst -R .
 ctags --kinds-c=p -oprototypes.lst -R .

You will get two files, one that lists function definitions and one with standalone function prototypes. You will need to diff these files (suitably massaged) to get a list of prototypes that have no corresponding definitions anywhere.
For the same thing with variables, use --kinds-c=v and --kinds-c=x. You can combine several kinds, like --kinds-c=fv.
I use Exuberant ctags, but there are other implementations out there which may or may not have these options.
